# Problems with jspdf installtion

Tags: npm, npm-install, jspdf

I was trying to install JSPDF using "npm install jspdf --save" command, but it is not getting installed.

It stops in the below line,

```
newProject: npm install jspdf --save
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠹ fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule jspdf@1.5.3 checking installable status
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I'm running into this as well.  Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using jspdf version 1.5.3, and there's no problem
you can use

> npm install jspdf

you don't need to add --save
or with version

> npm install jspdf@1.5.3